# Node.js store remote database locally (sync)

Tags: mysql, database, node.js

I have an app that uses this script to connect to a remote MySQL database:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var $          = require('jquery');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'somehost.com',
  user     : 'admin',
  password : 'admin',
  database : 'food'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    document.write('error connecting: ' + err.stack + '<br>');
    return;
  }

  document.write('Conectat cu ID ' + connection.threadId + '<br>');
});

connection.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  rows.forEach(function (item) {
    $("body").append('<span style="color: blue; font-weight: bold;">Denumire:</span> ' + item.denumire + ' <span style="color: blue; font-weight: bold;">Ingrediente:</span> ' + item.ingrediente + '<br>');
  })

});

connection.end();
```

The problem is I can't use the app when offline (internet may fail, but I still need to be able to use the app). 
Is there any way I can store the database locally when the app starts (actually store it, not in the session memory) so I can access the database even if I restart the app?

Comment: Use a local database like you are. You don't need internet connection to reach 127.0.0.1

Comment: You should put connection.query inside connect() callback. That doesn't guarantee the offline usage though when connecting to remote server. 127.0.0.1 is local server and needs no connection.

Comment: localhost is only for testing, that won't be the actual host. I've edited my post, so the `127.0.0.1` won't mislead you.

Comment: You need to write your own data synchronization system which is not trivial at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to replicate the database locally to a JSON file using this script:

```
connection.query('select * from database.table;', function(err, results, fields) {
    if (!err) {
      fs.writeFile('location\name.json', JSON.stringify(results), function(err) {});
    }
  });
```